# Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize() not working on android device

Tags: android, automation, mobile-chrome

I am receiving this error:

```
Platform = Android, Browser = chrome 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690
```

I am running the script on chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by switching the context to NATIVE_APP to get screen resolution and then again switch back to "WEBVIEW" or "CHROMIUM" which ever is applicable.

Below mentioned is the function I have used
driver.context("NATIVE_APP")